# How to calculate the average time difference of the actions of multiple users who have multiple entries by user?

Tags: sql, time, average, difference

Basically I have a table that has multiple users loaning out a book (for example) and returning it with a timestamp for both of these actions, they each have a unique ID , but they have multiple of these transactions. How would I go about finding the average time difference for each user based on all of their transactions? Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You also should indicate your rdbms

Comment: Apologies, I am new to the wonderful world of SQL so I am just beginning to grasp things. Thank you for the tip

Comment: This is also a nice thing to look http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/